# Can I call JScript functions or access JScript objects via DLR on the server side (ASP.Net)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, interop, dynamic-language-runtime

Is there a way to call JScript functions or access JScript objects via DLR on the server side (ASP.Net)?

This question is driven by the fact that there existed a way to call JScript from within *Silverlight* apps by the DLR. - Mr. Hejlsberg showed it on pdc '08 via DLR and the JavaScript-Binder [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/pdc2008/TL16). I didn't find any concrete information on that feature being present for ASP.Net; I even read that the binder was abandoned by Microsoft. - So I hope to get some information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN create JavaScript functions and register them on the server side, you CAN access those scripts, but (forgive me if I'm stating something that you already know, but just in case you don't know...) you CAN'T make the browser call the scripts whenever you want via the server (well, at least, with normal ways). A request is made, and a response is sent, and that's it. There is no logical ongoing connection between the browser and the server, and that's not possible, if that's what you wanted. Perhaps you may want to provide a simple example so we can help further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+ 1). I'm not an ASP.Net expert, but I know the mechanics of registering JScript the way you described. Well, my question is driven by the fact that there existed a way to call JScript from within _Silverlight_ apps by the DLR. - Mr. Hejlsberg showed it on pdc '08 via DLR and the JavaScript-Binder [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/pdc2008/TL16). I didn't find any concrete information on that feature being present for ASP.Net; I even read that the binder was abandoned by Microsoft. - So I hope to get some information here. (I updated my question.)

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20Language%20Support&referringTitle=Home, but there is, however no clear roadmap.